# Turkey e-Visa for Indian citizen with 2 year UK visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, turkey, e-visas

I have an Indian passport with a valid 2 year standard visitor visa for UK and I'm currently visiting UK to visit my son. Now we want to travel to Turkey for a week for holiday. Can we get e-Visa for Turkey and travel and come back to UK ?

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we get evisa for turkey and travel and come back to UK?

*Yes.*
You qualify for an e-visa. There does not appear to be any restrictions regarding your country of departure or return. When applying as an Indian passport holder via https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/ the following T&C appear:

- My passport covers the period that I will be staying in Türkiye.
- I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
- I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
- I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.

The IATA website https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/TR-Turkiye-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm# does not mention any departure/return country restrictions either.

See also https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/

Answer (score 0):

> Can we get e-Visa for Turkey and travel and come back to UK

Yes. Indian passport holders with valid UK/US/Schengen visas are eligible to get a "single entry" visa for Turkey. It costs $43 and is almost instantly sent to your email ID.

There is no option to get a multiple entry visa.